# How to scrape a span name in Nokogiri in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I want to scrape data off a website. The data is in the text of a `span`.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<p class="text-muted text-small">
  <span class="text-muted">Votes:</span>
  <span name="nv" data-value="1564808">1,564,808</span>
  <span class="ghost">|</span>                
  <span class="text-muted">Gross:</span>
  <span name="nv" data-value="107,928,762">$107.93M</span>
</p>
```

I want to search the whole page and get the value of the data-value which is `1,564,808` not the `107.93M` value.

I tried various ways to get the data, Like for instance:

```
@votes = []
html_content = 
open("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls057823854/sort=list_order,asc&st_
dt=&mod e=detail&page=1").read
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_content)
doc.css(".text-muted['span name=nv']").each do |i|
@votes << i.text.strip
```

Comment: Please show your code and what you have actually tried already. This is not a free code-writing site.

Comment: Done. Apologize. Been really struggling with this for a many hours already.

Comment: And how / why does your approach(es) fail with the supplied example? (I don't speak ruby, thus cannot answer - but I can nudge you to make others like your question :D )

Comment: It basically gives me a blank page. It does not get the info I need.

Comment: The url you provided returns a 404 so I can't test locally, could you correct it?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code isn't runnable. We need the minimal code we can run that demonstrates the problem. Without that you're asking us to rewrite your code just to guess whether that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
doc.css('div.lister-item-content > p.text-muted > span[name = nv]:nth-child(2)').map(&:text)
```

Which results in:

```
["1,564,941", "373,745", "2,004,624", "1,077,404", "887,189", "305,554", "207,904", "1,074,609", "748,393", "789,255", "1,224,753", "754,008", "634,752", "1,056,328", "1,604,158", "1,438,194", "629,504", "1,158,452", "517,609", "539,263", "1,443,979", "1,290,159", "161,981", "830,992", "1,427,193", "299,532", "289,184", "705,138", "615,264", "1,147,650", "1,030,826", "1,018,932", "921,730", "524,568", "557,482", "1,973,773", "813,743", "367,587", "342,800", "188,210", "649,467", "1,068,455", "547,990", "527,123", "805,964", "420,447", "441,780", "318,295", "1,004,742", "446,096", "203,977", "581,108", "1,754,019", "616,804", "484,534", "265,048", "958,244", "289,190", "651,605", "503,185", "320,564", "660,685", "476,016", "432,155", "588,572", "374,705", "378,561", "337,801", "463,467", "508,822", "187,810", "1,128,184", "221,361", "261,529", "322,314", "324,435", "116,258", "318,628", "1,334,595", "222,651", "1,155,754", "228,713", "205,956", "271,162", "293,774", "33,136", "80,385", "703,048", "195,712", "274,244", "233,133", "121,874", "208,462", "513,797", "485,112", "120,750", "135,232", "57,411", "125,431", "297,193"]
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Can you please explain what :nth-child(2) means?

Comment: @HDox I think it's originally(and in context of nokogiri selector) a css3 selector than a jQuery selector.